# parsing body body from \"\" failed, because invalid character 'G' looking for beginning of object key string

Tags: curl, post

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "@data.json"

{"code":400,"message":"parsing body body from \"\" failed, because invalid character 'G' looking for beginning of object key string"}
```

Comment: are you also having the problem in the context of weaviate? see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63098344/weaviate-error-code-400-parsing-body-from-failed-invalid-character-g-looki