# weaviate error code 400 parsing body from ... failed invalid character 'G' looking for beginning of object

Tags: curl, graphql, weaviate

I am trying to follow the steps at https://www.semi.technology/documentation/weaviate/current/client-libs/python.html and end up with the same problem as in:

[parsing body body from \"\" failed, because invalid character 'G' looking for beginning of object key string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62098140/parsing-body-body-from-failed-because-invalid-character-g-looking-for-be)

Since the other question never got an answer i am trying to ask with more detail in the weaviate context.

I tried the following python-unit test:

```py
'''
Created on 24.07.2020

@author: wf
'''
import unittest
import weaviate

class TestWeaviate(unittest.TestCase):
# https://www.semi.technology/documentation/weaviate/current/client-libs/python.html


    def setUp(self):
        pass


    def tearDown(self):
        pass
        

    def testWeaviate(self):
        ''' see https://www.semi.technology/documentation/weaviate/current/client-libs/python.html '''

        client = weaviate.Client("http://localhost:8080")
        try:
            client.create_schema("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/semi-technologies/weaviate-python-client/master/documentation/getting_started/people_schema.json")
        except:
            pass
        entries=[
           [ {"name": "John von Neumann"}, "Person", "b36268d4-a6b5-5274-985f-45f13ce0c642"],
           [ {"name": "Alan Turing"}, "Person", "1c9cd584-88fe-5010-83d0-017cb3fcb446"],
           [ {"name": "Legends"}, "Group", "2db436b5-0557-5016-9c5f-531412adf9c6" ]
        ]
        for entry in entries:
            dict,type,uid=entry
            try:
                client.create(dict,type,uid)
            except weaviate.exceptions.ThingAlreadyExistsException as taee:
                print ("%s already created" % dict['name'])
            
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
    unittest.main()
```

with the result:

```
John von Neumann already created
Alan Turing already created
Legends already created
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.370s

OK
```

(after rerunning)

Then i try:

```sh
curl http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '
{
  Get {
    Things {
      Group {
        name
        uuid
        Members {
          ... on Person {
            name
            uuid
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

getting the error:
{"code":400,"message":"parsing body body from "" failed, because invalid character 'G' looking for beginning of object key string"}

Comment: Note that the header states that you'll be sending JSON but the body is GraphQL. If you want to use curl check: https://www.semi.technology/documentation/weaviate/current/query-data/get.html#define-a-query maybe it is easier if you use Python though: https://www.semi.technology/documentation/weaviate/current/client-libs/python.html#query

Comment: @BobvanLuijt thx for the swift answer. I don't get  this. I tried to simply copy the command from your example page. Please answer with the correct command or update the documentation - this is currently a showstopper for my progress.

Comment: You're welcome, I've added a complete answer

Comment: I can't use the python code as long as i get weaviate.exceptions.UnexpectedStatusCodeException: Create class {'error': [{'message': "Name 'Person' already used as a name for a Thing class"}]}
 - and there is no example to cleanup up schemas and instances before starting. My python unit tests keep throwing exceptions all over because of the missing "clean start" point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The request expects a JSON object (because of `Content-type: application/json`) this can be added by setting `-d '{ "query": "{ # GRAPHQL QUERY }" }'` ([docs](https://www.semi.technology/documentation/weaviate/current/query-data/get.html#define-a-query)).

So in your case, the JSON object to send is:

```
{
  "query": 
  "{ 
     Get { 
       Things { 
         Group { 
           name uuid Members { ... on Person { name uuid } }  
         } 
       } 
     } 
  }"
}
```

Or the complete request:

```
$ curl http://localhost:8080/v1/graphql -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' -d '{
        "query": "{ Get { Things { Group { name uuid Members { ... on Person { name uuid } } } } } }"
    }'
```

with the result:

```
{"data":{"Get":{"Things":{"Group":[{"Members":null,"name":"Legends","uuid":"2db436b5-0557-5016-9c5f-531412adf9c6"}]}}},"errors":null}
```

Comment: Can you suggest what to fix? As I see it this exactly follows the documentation 

Comment: https://www.semi.technology/documentation/weaviate/current/client-libs/python.html#create-things-or-actions has a paragraph from which i did the cut&paste - it does not have the "query": part

Comment: Gotcha, thanks! Please note: https://github.com/semi-technologies/weaviate/issues/1217